# Not able to access AWS EC2 instance : Public DNS (IPv4) and IPv4 Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am not able to access Public DNS (IPv4) or IPv4 Public IP through browser and RDP.

I am able to ping the IPv4 from CMD.

This is my security group.

Type: All
Protocol: All
Port Range: All (0 - 65535)
Source: Anywhere

[image]

If i open URL: *ec2-3-19-142-8.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com* in browser, I am getting:

This site can't be reached

ec2-3-19-142-8.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com refused to connect.

[image]

Instance ID : *i-07023d288fc64babd*

RDP:

Remote desktop cant connect to remote computer.

```
1.) Remote access to server is not enable.
2.) Remote computer is turned off.
3.) The remote computer is not available on network.
```

Connect option in aws console gives error:

EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection)

There was a problem setting up the instance connection
Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.

[image]

Comment: On your server, there should be a service that must listen on a port like 80, 443.
Install Nginx or apache for the web server that will listen on 80 by default.

Comment: can you confirm that your webserver running

Comment: telnet show nothing is running on 80, i am not able to access it how do i install Nginx or apache? @Arun how to check webserver running?

Comment: you are doing the right thing, use telnet

Comment: @Naveen were you able to solve the issue? Im facing the same problem. I tried a lot of things suggested in the internet but the problem still exists, it refuses the connection